# How to filter results by time in apdex report - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to filter results by time in apdex report - Jmeter so that I can filter by steady state. I understand there is the Jmeter filter results tool but that provides only the aggregate csv report but not the jtl files to create apdex report.

Answer (score 0):

The [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) can be used to remove ramp-up and eventually ramp-down phases from the original .jtl results, something like:

```
FilterResults.bat --output-file steady.jtl --input-file original.jtl  --start-offset 120 --end-offset 360
```

where `--start-offset` and `--end-offset` are times in seconds so only metrics which are matching will be saved.

Once done you will be able to generate the reporting dashboard out of the `steady.jtl` file

Also there are `jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date` and `jmeter.reportgenerator.end_date` properties which can be used to set the report start and end dates, the default format is `yyyyMMddHHmmss`, if you want to amend it - there is `jmeter.reportgenerator.date_format` property.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Reporting configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)

Comment: Receiving following error when executing command - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jmeterplugins/save/MergeResultsService
        at org.jmeterplugins.tools.FilterResults.doJob(FilterResults.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jmeterplugins.save.MergeResultsService
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 10 more

Comment: You need to have [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) tool installed as well, please obtain it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) and the issue will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Use this python script to filter jtl file records which are in between timestamp

Your original file: sample.jtl
Filtered file: filtered.jtl
Filter between: 1661511913000 and 1661511914000

```py
import csv
csvFile = csv.reader(open(r"sample.jtl"),delimiter=',')
filtered = filter(lambda row: row[0] == 'timeStamp' or 1661511913000 <= int(row[0]) < 1661511914000, csvFile)
csv.writer(open(r"filtered.jtl",'w'),delimiter=',').writerows(filtered)
```

Then run the script `python filter-jtl.py`